# Django conditional querysets

Tags: sql, django, listview, conditional-statements, django-queryset

Alright,

So I'm using a general listview showing all orders where the payment hasn't been completed yet. Let's call them outstanding orders, orders which still require some sort of payment.

Orders contain one or multiple items and can contain zero or more payments.

So I want to compare the total order value, compare this value with the total payment and if these or not equal to zero, show them in the list.

Is there someway I can build a new queryset for items which do not meet a certain condition?

**views.py**

```
class OutstandingOrderListView(ListView):
model = Order 

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()[:5]
    for record in queryset.iterator():
        # Retrieve order_total
        order_total = record.item_set.aggregate(total=Sum('price'))['total']
        # Retrieve payment_total
        payment_total = record.payment_set.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total']
        # Compare both
        delta = order_total - payment_total

        if delta != 0:
            print("These guys owe you money!")
            # Add record to new queryset?
```

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    no = models.CharField(max_length=9, default=increment_order_number, 
        editable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='created_by')

class Item(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, 
        decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('000.00'))

class Payment(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, 
        default=Decimal('000.00'))
```

Tried to use filtering on annotations like @bdbd mentioned in the comments, in this case we could use exclude():

```
queryset = Order.objects.annotate(order_total=Sum('item__price')) \
        .annotate(payment_total=Sum('payment__amount')) \
        .exclude(order_total=F('payment_total'))[:5]
```

Even though this works, the second annotation shows very unusual results, not sure why but it looks like a multiple from order_total...

Comment: Have a look at [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate). You can annotate those two aggregated totals, and filter the queryset on rows that have `order_total < payment_total`

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models?

Comment: Just edited the question and added the models though shortened for readability.

Comment: @bdbd I tried using to exclude all orders where the order_total is equal to payment_total, this does however get me some strange results.

Comment: Sorry I know I suggested annotations, but apparently its a known [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060). Even the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) explicitly warn about it. But it does suggest using `distinct=True`. Can you try with that? So `Sum('payment__amount', distinct=True)` and `Sum('item__price', distinct=True)`

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can try aggregating using [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: You just beat me to it, I used subqueries and it does exactly what we need here. I read there where know issues chaning multiple annotations together. I will edit my answer with the final query I'm currently using! Thank you!